# Play audio .flac vs .fla in IIS via virtual directory

Tags: iis, audio, flac, fla

I do have an audio angular app with Microsoft dotnet core 6 backend and many audio files accesses via virtual directory.  I can access any files except files with .flac extension (I have added .flac and audio/flac to mime type file in IIS).  The error code is 404.  However, if I change the file extension from .flac to .fla then it works and I can play it as Flac file.
How can I tell the iis to accept/ access the .flac file?
I am running windows 10 64bit with IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: To learn what happens to .flac, enable FRT and reproduce the 404 error. Then the log file(s) can tell why.

Comment: Have you tried to test another mime type : `audio/x-flac`, or check if it work with `application/octet-stream`. As far as I know, there is no such type file as `.fla`, or it may be a type recognized by other 3rd party software. And as already mentioned, using FRT to view log files would be good advice.

Comment: the audio/x-flac mime type doesn't work.  The only way I can make it to work is to change the file ext. to .fla (if you look at the mime type in IIS, yes you will see ".fla".  When I try to access the .flac file, the IIS give me 404 error.  I change it to '.fla' then it recognize it and the error 404 is gone away.  I did google the issue.  It seems that people have had the same issue by using different format instead.  However, I don't think it is the right solution. It should be 'real solution' for this since browsers now play 'flac' file.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, if this is the case, I think you have to find the reason of this issue via FRT as mentioned above, this should be better help solve this problem.

Comment: I decide to create a tiny test app in this case. I put it in my repos, https://github.com/d052057/FlacTest.  You're welcome and download and run this tiny app. It is require VS2022 and a few instructions to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the MIME type in the root of IIS - not in the individual site settings.

I've set .flac to audio/flac and Chrome streams it fine.

Good luck!