# Download Flac file from IIS

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, iis-8, flac

I do have several audio files in a directory. In program.CS (vs2022 - Angular 14 with c# backend), I used static files or serverfiles to access the directory.  The directory is set to be browseable and anyone can browse it and pick any files to download to their local storage.  This work very well for any files except files with flac extension.  When I click on the flac file to download, I got error 404.   I do have another post regarding playing flac audio file which I do have the same issue - error 404.  Please see [Play audio .flac vs .fla in IIS via virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73595064/play-audio-flac-vs-fla-in-iis-via-virtual-directory)

I don't know why Microsoft IIS did not work or like file with FLAC extension.  I did report it as a bug to Microsoft but I got no response.

Does any body know any issues with Microsoft IIS and FLAC file extension?

Thanks.

Comment: It is well known that web servers (not only IIS) won't enable MIME types for all kinds of stuffs by default and server administrators like you need to enable extra items according to user manuals.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why Microsoft IIS did not work or like file with FLAC extension. I did report it as a bug to Microsoft but I got no response.

Because it's not a bug. You'll need to add a `mimeMap` to your website (either by using the IIS Manager or adding it to your `web.config` manually):

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".flac" mimeType="audio/x-flac" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: It is still not working.  Please visit my tiny code regarding flac file https://github.com/d052057/FlacTest.  I tested both on mimetypes audio/x-flac and audio/flac.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when testing? According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#flac), the content-type for FLAC is `audio/flac` or `audio/x-flac`.

Comment: I have done both audio/x-flac and audio/flac.  None of them works.  Error code is 404.

Comment: This is my update as of 10/10/2022:  I deployed my web app to a widows 10 pro and the FLAC issue is gone away.  However, the issue is still occured on my developped machine which I have windows 11, VS2022 and IIS installed.  If I deploy my app to my local machine which is a windows 11 and the FLAC file is NOT WORKING.  For those who try to help me, please be aware of this issue.  Thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.